# Magento 1.9 - How to change product text field attribute backend_type from varchar to decimal?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have customer attribute called `carat` as a type `textfield` and `backend_type = varchar` in my store.

- I need to use this attribute in `Advanced Search` page as a `range`
  attribute.
- If I'll change `backend_type = varchar` to `decimal` from database directly then it works as `range` attribute. But I didn't get any result in search page.
- I can not delete this attribute and and create new attribute because it's already used in api's and in some other functionality also.
- How can I change attribute type and get store values as it is?

Comment: any one have any idea about this?

Comment: this works for me 
http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/magento-convert-attribute-type/
just need to do some changes as per requirement..